# Create Content Type Button

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm pretty new to drupal development.

I have a group node and inside it a content type called efforts. To this efforts i need to add a calendar and I also need to a add a create event button inside the effort page. the event is another content type that I created for the calendar.

I already created the two content types for handling events and efforts. I also added a calendar view to the effort. I need to add a create event button to the effort page.

Can some one tell me how do i do this ? How do i add a block which contains the create event button to the effort page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [nodereference_url](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module.  You will add a nodereference field on the event content type that only allows Effort nodes to be referenced.  This then allows you to create a link on the Effort page like "Create a new event for this effort", takes you to the node/add/event with the node reference field already filled in with that Effort where you clicked the link.  The 2 are forevermore linked and views relationships can do the rest.   Hope that helps.

Comment: Also I have another similar problem. Can i reference multiple nodes ?

I have 4 different content types - efforts, users, objectives and groups. Groups and users can share the objectives and efforts. If a user creates a objective and other users/groups want to share the same objective, Can I do something like that ?